# PostgreSQL error: function returning record called in context that cannot accept type record, on remote dblink call

Tags: postgresql-9.6, dblink

When I run this code:

```
do
$func$
declare cmd text;
begin

    cmd = FORMAT($$ select public.func_doit('%s'::date, '%s'::date); $$,'2019-01-01', '2019-03-01');

    PERFORM DBLINK('my_conn', cmd);


end;

$func$
```

I receive the following error:

> SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: function returning record called in context that cannot accept type record
>     Where: SQL statement "SELECT DBLINK('my_conn', cmd)"
>   PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 12 at PERFORM
>     ERROR: function returning record called in context that cannot accept type record
>     Where: SQL statement "SELECT DBLINK('my_conn', cmd)"
>   PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 12 at PERFORM
>     ERROR: function returning record called in context that cannot accept type record
>     Where: SQL statement "SELECT DBLINK('my_conn', cmd)"
>   PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 12 at PERFORM

The function being called: `public.func_doit`, `RETURNS void`.

There is no ***record*** in the mix as referenced by the error message. The function just does something and there's nothing to return.

After placing notices inside the called function, non are posted, which means that the function doesn't even begin to execute.

I know the function works because when I call it directly from its local DB, it works as expected, with the same parameters.

`PERFORM` is the right statement to use here because the function doesn't return anything.

And I also tried: `...perform * from public.func_doit...`, which throws a syntax error.

What could I be missing here?

Comment: dblink does return a record, try **select * from dblink...** check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/contrib-dblink-function.html

Comment: Yeah, tried that and since the function called returns void, not sure what to set the AS portion of the `select * from dblink(..) as t(??)` when set to text it throws an error. I tried 'ANY' as well, and still get error.